# How to get the ON_DESTROY lifecycle event in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

I want to get the lifecycle event `ON_DESTROY` in my composable, therefore I found the following code in the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect). Adjusted to my use case it looks like this:

```
DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            currentOnDestroy()
        }
    }

    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

    onDispose {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

However the problem is that the `onDispose` is called before the `LifecycleEventObserver` can emit the `ON_DESTROY` event. My first solution was to add that event to the `onDispose` function.

```
onDispose {
    currentOnDestroy()
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

But I don't think that this is the right solution. So my question is, how do I get the Lifecycle event ON_DESTROY in a composable?

Comment: `removeObserver` is not required, see https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5

Comment: Compose doesn't recompose once the Lifecycle reaches STOPPED, so I don't think this is will ever fire. Can you explain why you are trying to listen for `ON_DESTROY`? It would be helpful if you included what your `currentOnDestroy` is actually doing.

Comment: The reason was to report to the viewmodel, which is injected into the composable can report the onDestroy event to our analytics system. That task was solved in another way. However I was curious if I can listen to the `ON_DESTROY` in a composable, since the documentation gives an example to listen to `ON_START` and `ON_STOP`.